# Apache POI Enable excel editing

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to edit Excels in Java. After editing POI is not able to save file because the Excel is always protected. If you open, it will show the option to enable editing. On copying same file to a new Excel will work fine. But is there any way to enable editing from Java for the Excel? Here is a sample of my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    "New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx"));
            // Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get();
            // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                // Get first sheet from the workbook
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);

                // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();

                    // For each row, iterate through each columns
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        // Do something
                    }

                }
            }
            file.close();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                    "New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx");
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Done!!!!!!!!");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using excel 2007.

Comment: Could you show us the code - what you have tried?

Comment: Do you perhaps already have the Excel file open when you try to save it? Windows is very picky about letting you write to an open file is all... (Linux and Mac are both much more permissive in that regard)

Comment: The file was not opened anywhere.This is the code which I am trying to execute after creating new XSSFWorkbook file.close();
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("New Microsoft Excel Worksheet (2).xlsx");
   workbook.write(out);
   out.close();

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code in it instead of in a comment.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013 POI 3.16 and have the same problem. I'm using web services and making the call through the browser. I have both Chrome and Firefox set to save the file rather than open it. When opening it, Excel has it protected from editing. After clicking Enable Edit, the spreadsheet then populates the formulas and performs the calculations. Would prefer if the Enable Edit step were eliminated. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried `XSSFSheet.disableLocking()` and `XSSFSheet.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true)`. Neither nor both worked.

Comment: I also tried `wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll()` as per https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#Formula+Evaluation+and+SXSSF and still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So this turns out to be a Office Trust Center setting. When there is potentially unsafe content in the file being opened it will open in protected view, no matter what POI settings are in place.

I was able to work around it by setting my browser to save the file to a folder rather than opening it directly (which actually saves it to a temp folder). Then I added that folder to the Trusted Locations in the Trust Center for Office. This tells office that it's ok to open this file for editing because I trust the location from which it is being opened.

[Office support link describing this setting.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-Protected-View-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653)

For Excel 2013 - Click `File` tab, then select `Options`, `Trust Center`, `Trust Center Settings`.

[image: File->Options]

Add your location where the downloads will be stored.

[image: Add new location]

Ensure your directory is added.

[image: See new location added.]

While I agree this is not a POI solution, it IS a solution. Yes you will probably have to help your end user to set this up.

Perhaps soon, Apache POI team will add a POI solution into a future release to do this programmatically.

Comment: Maybe adding the author of the end user if possible would also eliminate this process. `WorkBook.getSummaryInformation().setAuthor(endUserName)`.