# Editing Excel spreadsheet in Java/Android using Apache POI writes data but Excel demands repairs

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I am attempting to build an Android app as a convenience wrapper for editing an Excel spreadsheet. I am using the Apache POI to interface with Excel in Java, which [should be able to edit an existing workbook](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook). The spreadsheet has no fancy formatting and the editing just changes or adds numbers. I can successfully read and write data to file. However, when I open the file in Microsoft Excel (either on mobile or on PC after transferring the file), I receive the following error message:

> We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

If I click yes, it opens the file in Read-only mode. All the data is there, nothing is missing. However, to edit the file in Excel, I must save it to a different filename, which is rather inconvenient. While I could in-principle work around it (I shouldn't need to open the file in Excel often), it seems symptomatic of more serious problems.

I have a hunch it is tangentially related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294690/apache-poi-enable-excel-editing), where Excel was suspicious of a file which had been edited by an "untrusted" program. However, unlike that question where the file was opened in Protected Mode, here Excel is implying that the file is somehow damaged. Perhaps the issue is in the metadata?

Below is a minimum working example. When the user clicks on a button the selectFile method is called. This uses the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) to obtain the URI of the .xlsx file I want to edit, which is an Excel spreadsheet I created in Excel to be blank except for a number in cell A1 in Sheet1. The file is stored locally on my device (although I get the same problem when it is on OneDrive, which is where I actually want the file). This URI is then passed to the doEverything method, which does the actual work of editing the Excel file. (It also updates a textView with ID textView_data, which displays the value found in cell A1. This shows that it is reading the data properly.)

```java
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mText;

    /**
     * Opens the given workbook, increments the cell by 1, then writes and closes it.
     *
     * @param uri URI of XLSX file
     */
    private void doEverything(Uri uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            return;
        }
        XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
        // Open the workbook
        try (InputStream inp = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)) {
            wb = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
            // Increment cell A1 by 1.
            XSSFCell cell = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue()+1);
            // Write the value of the cell to the saved textView.
            mText.setText(Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (wb != null) {
            try (OutputStream fileOut = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri)) {
                // Write to file.
                wb.write(fileOut);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Record the various Views we'll need later
        mText = findViewById(R.id.textView_data);
    }

    /**
     * Asks the user to select a .xlsx file. Called when the user presses a button.
     */
    public void selectFile(View view) {
        // Open an .xlsx file
        openDoc.launch(new String[]{"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
    }

    // GetContent creates an ActivityResultLauncher<String> to allow you to pass
    // in the mime type you'd like to allow the user to select
    ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> openDoc = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
                    doEverything(uri);
                }
            });
}
```

I am using Apache POI version 5.2.3. I am using the Microsoft Excel mobile app (Version 1.0.1 (16.0.15629.20092), 2018) and Excel 365 on desktop (Version 2209), both of which give the same issue. My phone uses Android 12 with SDK 31.

How can I edit the file without Excel thinking the file is broken?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error by editing a simple xlsx file with your code on my computer. It correctly increments the value of the first cell; there are no errors upon opening the edited file.

Comment: @JanezKuhar Hmm, odd.

Comment: Have you tried running your example in a standalone Java desktop project? Just the part that makes use of the Apache POI API.

Comment: @JanezKuhar Not yet. I'm yet to set up any standalone Java desktop projects. That would probably help narrow down where the problem is, though.

Comment: I've inspected the damaged file. There seems to be some corruption in how the files have been zipped (.xlsx is a ZIP archive of XML files) (Unix unzip says "mismatch between local and central GPF bit 11 ("UTF-8")"), suggesting some kind of encoding error.